# Confidence interval for evaluating an integral via Monte-Carlo sampling

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, monte-carlo, integral

I am trying to evaluate the following integral using Monte-Carlo:
$$
\langle f \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x~ \rho(x) f(x)
$$
where $\rho(x)$ is a normalized positive function. The integration is performed by generating $N$ random values of $x_j$ whose distribution satisfies $\rho(x)$, and evaluate
$$
\langle f \rangle \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} f(x_j)
$$

I am looking for a way to evaluate the confidence interval of $\langle f \rangle$. If $f(x_j)$ obeys normal distribution, the confidence interval can be obtained using Student's t distribution. However, this is not the case because, among other reasons, in my case $f$ **have a finite range**. Is there a generalized algorithm/expression for confidence interval regardless of the distribution of $f(x_j)$?

My background in statistics is very limited, so if this is a well-known problem available in books/online courses I would also be happy to learn about it.

Comment: The Normal approximation is a consequence of the Central Limit Theorem, assuming the estimator has a variance. An exact confidence interval would require the knowledge of the distribution of $f(X)$.

Comment: Stripped of its details, and setting $y_j=f(x_j),$ this question says, "I have a random sample of data $y_j:$ how do I find a confidence interval for the mean?"  As @Xi'an points out, that requires making some assumptions about the possible distributions this variable might have.  For all we know, the underlying distribution has no mean or the mean is infinite.

Comment: @whuber I am pretty sure that a finite mean exists because the integrand is the product of a normalized function $\rho$ and a function $f$ that has a finite range. And if an exact CI requires complete knowledge of the distribution, I want to know if there is a good way to estimate CI for a sample $y_j$ that has a finite range?

Comment: You don't need "complete knowledge" of the distribution.  Limiting your assumptions to a finitely parameterized family is usually enough to construct a good CI procedure.  There isn't any general procedure for values in a finite range, but if you have definite upper and lower bounds, you can make progress.